# Can I use google class room share api without including js files

Tags: google-classroom

I want to use google class room share button without including share button js files.

what those js files do is they opens an popup having url like, https://classroom.google.com/share?url=URL_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE&title=TITLE_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE_WITH&body=DESCRIPTION

could I give a google share button and on its click open an popup with above url?
is it safe to use share api this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 9/28/15**: The engineering team and confirmed that this URL pattern, `https://classroom.google.com/share?url=...`, is considered stable and supported, and can be used in place of the share button if desired.

I'm unsure if manually constructing the popup URLs would even work, but it certainly isn't a supported use of the technology. The Classoom team are free to change internal details like that URL at any time without warning, so it isn't safe to rely on it. I would recommend sticking to the methods outlined in the documentation.

Comment: The linked blog post shows an example URL as `https://classroom.google.com/share?url=https://foo.com/`, but `https://foo.com/` should probably be encoded/escaped.